# How to sort an array on grouping

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents with the following structure:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("..."),
    "group_id" : 1,
    "value" : 4,
    "date": "1970-01-01"
}
```

I wish to group my documents by `group_id` and then make a sorted array of the docs included in that group. For now, I can only build an unsorted array:

```
db.collection.aggregate({$group: {_id: "$group_id", count: {$sum: 1}, docs: {$push: "$$CURRENT"}}})
```

How can I order my documents in my array based for example on `value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first sort your documents by "group" then by "value" in ascending order using the [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) by group pipeline operator.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$sort": { "group_id": 1, "value": 1 } },
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$group_id", 
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }, 
        "docs": { "$push": "$$CURRENT" }
    }}
])
```